# How do to read specific data by the id from xml in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I wanted to select a specific data based on its id and here are the example of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<productdetails>
    <product>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <product_name>banana</product_name>
        <product_price>5.00</product_price>
        <product_description>its banana</product_description>
        <product_quantity>12</product_quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <product_name>mango</product_name>
        <product_price>10.00</product_price>
        <product_description>its mango</product_description>
        <product_quantity>12</product_quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <product_name>orange</product_name>
        <product_price>3.00</product_price>
        <product_description>its orange</product_description>
        <product_quantity>1</product_quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <product_name>apple</product_name>
        <product_price>4.00</product_price>
        <product_description>its apple</product_description>
        <product_quantity>1</product_quantity>
    </product>
</productdetails>
```

What im trying to do is store them back in a different but temporary xml file to then be calculated in GridView.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood your query correctly. You could search for specific data based on its Id using Linq. For example,

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);  
var idToSearch = 1;
var result= root.Elements("product")
                .Where(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("Id").Value)==idToSearch)
                .Select(x=>new 
                           {
                             ProductName=x.Element("product_name").Value,
                             Price=x.Element("product_price").Value
                           });
```

Comment: Do i just put this in the .cs? Im not really sure what Linq is and the code doesnt seems familiar to me especially the .Where and .Search part

Comment: You would need to include System.Linq namespace. You could read more on Linq here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/

Comment: Linq allows you to query xml, json, in-memory collection, sql etc. The methods such as 'Where' are basically extension methods on IEnumerable, which Linq brings makes use of.